# How to discover the queues in a LDP server

Tags: printing

I've a minimal Ubuntu installation, and I've heard that is possible to print to a LDP server directly with the lpr command:

```
   $ rlpr --printer=hp4l@foo.bar.orgfile.txt
```

I know the lpd ip but not the queue name, so I wonder if exist a tool to request it to the LDP server, I've seen that MacOs and Ubuntu with cups are capable of guessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've just found a way to print without installing cups =), I just had the weird idea that it was necessary to print anything:

```
    rlpr -h -Plp -HHERE_IP_OF_THE_LPD_SERVER foo.ps
```